# How to make a table perfectly fill inside a panel?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

For example I made a following panel with a table inside a panel. The panel size is 500 x 280.

```
<asp:Panel ID="welcomePanel" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="3px" Height="280px" Width="500px" BackColor="White">
    <table class="tableInPanel">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #F0F0F0"><strong><span>Welcome To</span><br/><span>my website</span></strong></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more rows...-->
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

And here is my CSS for the table:

```
.tableInPanel {
    width: 500px;
    height: 280px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The only problem of this is that it does not work in Google Chrome, the bottom of the table exceed the height of the panel so that the table cover up the bottom border of the panel (it looks ugly). However, it works perfectly in Firefox and IE. As for Safari, the bottom of the table is just slightly more than what it should be, and cover a little bit of the bottom border.

Is there a better way or alternative way to do this in order to make sure it will always works and works fine in different browsers ?

What it looks like in Firefox:
[image: Image in FireFox]

What it looks like in Google Chrome:
[image: Image in Chrome]

Comment: can you please share this in JSFiddle or any screen shot, atleast?

Comment: @LeonMa why are there two `height` attributes in your css?

Comment: @Reddy I have tried only put height: 280px (this was my very first thing I did), Chrome still shows it like the second picture i put. It is just don't make any sense. Other browsers work fine though.

Comment: It won't help you out that way by adding two height attributes,  and set the border to table than to panel..

Comment: Setting border to your table than to your panel must fix your issue right?

Comment: @Reddy You got it man, didn't think about it. Thanks.